# position text relative above an other text

Tags: html, css

I wish to position a text fragment above an other part of the same line:

```
<div>Th<div class="ac">Am</div>is is an ex<div class="ac">E</div>ample line</div>
```

would show

```
  Am         E
This is an example line
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you set up an [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I had tried several css3 and js things but without the proper knowledge. None where working. And for sure not as beautiful like the answer from red-X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with the following setup:

```
.ac {
    position:relative; /*relative to the position it had in the line*/
    top:-1em; /*move up exactly one line*/
    width:0px; /*don't keep the width in the original line*/
    display:inline-block; /*dont add a line break*/
}
body {
    font-family:monospace
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kf2rb83x/

Comment: Glad I could help Eric, welcome to SO. If the answer was sufficiënt you can mark it as the solution with the checkmark on the left of this answer.